# Abrir dirección en GoogleMaps, al clickar en el textview

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, android-intent

Tengo un `textview` donde me muestra datos de mi base de datos y me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para al clickar en el `textview` que contiene la dirección, que me abra dicha dirección en GoogleMaps.

Agradecería también que me dijerais como lo hago a través de un icono de GoogleMaps, que me recoja esa dirección del `textview`, y abra este también en GoogleMaps.
Me sirven las dos opciones.

Muchas gracias, si necesitáis algún código de la app, me lo decís.

> tvDireccion.setText(rs.getString(2));

Así es como paso al textview la información de la BD SQL a través de una consulta.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.tvTlf1:
            //Si está vacio no estará disponible para clickar
            if(tvTlf1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){

            }else{
                //Marcará la variable phone (tvTlf1.getText) en el teléfono del móvil
                String phone = tvTlf1.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
                //Ejecuta el intent
                startActivity(intent);

                break;
            }
```

Aquí por ejemplo al clickar en el `textview` del teléfono, me abre la app teléfono con el número del `textview`. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me faltaría algo de contexto de tu aplicación para poder darte una respuesta concreta.
Pero si lo que quieres es agregar un evento al touch de un textView, para que este te abra un WebView con Google Maps, apuntando a la dirección que tenia este TextView en el texto, seria cuestión de agregar el siguiente código al switch statement del textView que contendrá la dirección:

```
String map = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + direccion; 
// Donde direccion es la variable que contiene el string del textview

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(map));
startActivity(i);
```

fuente:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987551/how-to-open-google-maps-using-address

Comment: Creo que justo esto es lo que buscaba, mañana por la mañana lo probaré, que no hoy no puedo, y te comento el resultado, gracias!!

Comment: Buenas, he probado tu solución y me ha sido muy exitosa!! Gracias